# How to read space, comma and newline separated integers from a file into an array of vectors in C++?

Tags: c++, file, c++11, vector, graph

I have a file format like this:

> 1 80,982  163,8164 170,2620..
>   
>   2 42,1689 163,1689   5,8026..
>   
>   ....

I also share the image of the file format:
[Image of the file format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/67Be3.jpg)

where the first number represent the starting vertex of a graph.The second number separated by a space represent the destination vertex and the third number separated by a comma represent the weight of the edge connected by that two vertices.

For example- In the first row the number 1 means the starting vertex, 80 is the destination vertex and the weight of the edge is 982.

Here my code:

```
void addedge(vector <pair<int,int> > adj[],int start,int stop,int weight)
  {
   adj[start].push_back(make_pair(stop,weight));
   adj[stop].push_back(make_pair(start,weight));
  }

void print(vector <pair<int,int> > adj[],int num)
{   for(int i=0;i<num;i++)
    {
    cout<<i<<"\t";
    for(vector<pair<int,int> >::const_iterator iter=adj[i].begin();iter!=adj[i].end();iter++)
    {
        cout<<iter->first<<"\t";
        cout<<iter->second<<"\t";
    }
    cout<<endl; 
}


  int main()
  {
   int start,stop,weight,source,count=0;
  //    cout<<"Enter the number of vertices: ";
  //    cin>>num;
        vector <pair<int,int>> adj[200];
  //    cout<<"\nEnter (-1 -1 -1) for exit: ";
  /*    while(1)
        {
         cout<<"\nEnter the vertices and weight: ";
         cin>>start>>stop>>weight;
         if(start==-1 && stop==-1 && weight==-1)
            break;
          addedge(adj,start,stop,weight);
         }
  */}
```

Here I put the code of user interface.But I do not understand how to read the integers from the file and make the graph.

I am new in C++.I tried a lot but I could not figure it out.

Comment: Please post your file format as text, not images.  For people that can't see images for one reason or another your question is unanswerable.

Comment: Those look like tabs, not spaces.

Comment: The other reason you shouldn't post images is that if one of us would like to run your program, we have to type in all of those numbers instead of simply copying and pasting the data.